# Comparison of URL from CSV is not working with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, url

Well am trying to compare certain records in csv using python pandas. Unfortunately it is not able to detect the records with exact URL.
For further explanation find below code

```
 def find_function_name(self,file_path,line):
        fn_data = pd.read_csv(constant.MAP_PARSER_FILE)
        print(fn_data.head())
        print(file_path)
        print(line)
        function_details=fn_data.loc[(fn_data['Filepath'] == 'C:\Users\PATH\TO\FOLDER\Model\Wireless.php')]
        print(function_details)
        sys.exit()
```

CSV Structure as below

```
Filepath    FunctionName    StartLine   EndLine
C:\Users\PATH\TO\FOLDER\Model\Wireless.php  getSampleThroughput 2174    2231
C:\Users\PATH\TO\FOLDER\Model\Wireless.php  getSampleThroughput 205 351
C:\Users\PATH\TO\FOLDER\Model\Wireless.php  getSampleThroughput 361 439
C:\Users\PATH\TO\FOLDER\Model\Wireless.php  getSampleThroughput 449 528
C:\Users\PATH\TO\FOLDER\Model\Wireless.php  getSampleThroughput 532 802
```

May I know what is missing in my code to perform proper comparison.

Comment: You are comparing `FunctionName` column with path instead of `Filepath` column.

Comment: @Hasnat I have modified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare like this. I think you might want to compare it with Filepath column instead of FunctionName.

```
function_details = fn_data[fn_data['Filepath'] == r'C:\Users\PATH\TO\FOLDER\Model\Wireless.php']
```

Comment: I have modified the code and then it is not showing any records ,returning an empty dataframe.

Comment: I think the issue is related to backward slash in url

Comment: Got this error
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Try using `r'C:\Users\PATH\TO\FOLDER\Model\Wireless.php'` or `'C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FOLDER\\Model\\Wireless.php'`

Comment: I need to filter the same with more condition function_details=fn_data.loc[(fn_data['Filepath'] == r'{}'.format(file_path)) & (fn_data['StartLine'].ge(2174))]

Comment: But it is not giving result